# JQuery tabs on an initial hidden asp.net panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

in my asp.net project I have a panel and on it a jquery tabs div.
Initially the panel is hidden and it is shown if I click a button.

This is the very simple code:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul id="none">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Asset details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Structure details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Audit Info</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">Some Content for tab 1</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Some Content for tab 2</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Some Content for tab 3</div>
    </div>
```

And jquery code:

```
function myfunction() {

$("#tabs").tabs();
```

}

The problem is that when I show the panel the tabs div is visible but not formatted.

All run correctly if I set a delay on myfunction:

```
function myfunction() {

//$("#tabs").tabs();

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
}, 500);
```

}

Is there a way to solve this problem in a more secure way?

Here the missing code:

The button that show my panel on click:

```
<my:RoundedButton ID="BillingDataButton" runat="server" 
SkinID="Small"
Text="Billing data" 
OnClick="BillingDataButton_Click"
```

/>

Code behind:

```
protected void BillingDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BillingDataPanel.Show();

    }
```

I've tryed this (thanks Michael):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

});

But when I click my button and panel is shown the result is:

[image]

**Update - A possible solution**

Added this code in my asp.net page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {

    myfunction();

});
```

This ensures that the jquery code for displaying the tab is executed at the end of the request. No setTimeout is requested in this case.

Please inform me if exixt a better solution.

Comment: I don't see the code that shows the div, but if I understand correctly, you should first create tabs and then show the div.

Comment: Hi Claudio, I've added missing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior actually, but there is a cleaner solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

You see, jQuery can't make all modifications before the DOM is fully available. This is why the delay works for you, but it's by happenstance. Had this been run on a much slower browser it would have failed most assuredly.

Leveraging the `document.ready` event however is a much more stable, preferred, and accepted solution amongst the community. In fact, you really shouldn't do **anything** in jQuery outside of this method as far as *initialization* is concerned.

Comment: Hi Michael and thanks for your answer. If I user your solution when I show the panel (initially it's hidden) I see tab div but not formatted. As if the statement $("#tabs").tabs() had not been entered.

Comment: don't worry I correct your code myself but problem remains. It is as if the javascript code should be executed by force after  panel show. Please see edit.

Comment: @jacktric, where are you placing the `$(document).ready...` code?

Comment: In my asp.net page under <asp:Content> tag.